# MySQL sum column and compare it to a given value

Tags: mysql, string, compare, sum

I need to display a set of result of available room from DB in which conditions are:

1. alm_num = 1
2. alm_date between 26-29 Nov 2012
3. and sum_num > or = 3

Then I compose mySQL like this:

```
select sum(villas_allotment.alm_num) as sum_num, 
villas_allotment.alm_id as aid, villas_db.v_name as vname  
from villas_allotment 
inner join villas_db on villas_allotment.alm_vid=villas_db.v_id 
where alm_num='1' 
and alm_date between '2012-11-26' and '2012-11-29' 
and alm_vid='3' 
and sum_num>='3'
```

But I've got :

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'sum_num' in 'where clause'
```

So could you guys please suggest me how to survive from this error.
Regards,

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `HAVING` for conditions on aggregated columns:

```
select
    sum(villas_allotment.alm_num) as sum_num, 
    villas_allotment.alm_id as aid,
    villas_db.v_name as vname  
from villas_allotment 
inner join villas_db on villas_allotment.alm_vid = villas_db.v_id 
where alm_num = '1' 
and alm_date between '2012-11-26' and '2012-11-29' 
and alm_vid = '3' 
group by villas_allotment.alm_id, villas_db.v_name
having sum(villas_allotment.alm_num) >= 3
```

You also needed a `group by` clause on the non-aggregated columns, which I added in for you.

Comment: May I have a question? Why I need an extra group by. (I'm poor of mySQL).

Comment: According to your code. It seems like I don't need `sum(villas_allotment.alm_num) as sum_num, ` as you don't mentioned `sum_num` any where else the code. Do I?

Comment: I've got a problem. The code is not choose aid where `sum(villas_allotment.alm_num)>=3`. alm_num(int) only contains 0 and 1.